# "The system time has changed" events after waking from sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, sleep

Sometimes when my computer running Windows 7 wakes up from sleep, it has to adjust the time. When this happens the following system event is logged:

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
    <System>
        <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General' Guid='{A68CA8B7-004F-D7B6-A698-07E2DE0F1F5D}'/>
        <EventID>1</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime='2010-03-06T19:09:57.500000000Z'/>
        <EventRecordID>10672</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation/>
        <Execution ProcessID='4' ThreadID='56'/>
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Computer>GAME</Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name='NewTime'>2010-03-06T19:09:57.500000000Z</Data>
        <Data Name='OldTime'>2010-03-06T17:34:32.870117200Z</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture='sl-SI'>
        <Message>The system time has changed to ‎2010‎-‎03‎-‎06T19:09:57.500000000Z from ‎2010‎-‎03‎-‎06T17:34:32.870117200Z.</Message>
        <Level>Information</Level>
        <Task></Task>
        <Opcode>Info</Opcode>
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Provider>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General</Provider>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>Time</Keyword>
        </Keywords>
    </RenderingInfo>
</Event>
```

When this happens (I noticed it twice until now) the old time always corresponds to the time when computer entered sleep. The problem is that if Windows Media Center is scheduled for recording during this time, it just skips it as if the computer was turned off. I never had this problem running Windows Vista on the same machine.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem and how to solve it are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the system's clock battery is low on power ? See if changing it helps.

Comment: I haven't thought of that possibility. Though, shouldn't the time reset if the battery failed, instead of just stop? I guess changing it can't hurt either so I'll do it at the earliest convenience, nevertheless.

Comment: @DamirArh Did replacing the battery solve the problem?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Yes, it did. I'm not using the computer for Windows Media Center recording as often as I did, but still there were no skipped recordings since I've changed the battery.